# Why is $S^n \cong \bar{B^n}$?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

In class when my professor first introduced complexes and cells, he gave some examples of closed $n-$cells, (where he defines X as a closed $n$-cell if $X\cong \bar{B}^n$) and one thing he said was

> > $S^n\cong \bar{B^n}$ is a closed $n$-cell

I'm really struggling to see why $S^n\cong \bar{B}^n$. I should note that I am $\textbf{very}$ new at topology and thinking about these types of geometric figures, so please forgive me and bear with me. So,  $S^n$ is basically the boundary of $B^{n+1}$ right? And $B^n$ is filled in where $S^n$ is just a boundary. So it's really hard for me to picture how this works.

Further, he says

> > $S^n\setminus \{p\}\cong R^n$ is an open n-cell

But that's essentially the same as saying $S^n\setminus \{p\}\cong B^n$ Because $B^n\cong R^n$, right? So what does removing one single point from the n-sphere do so drastically to make it go from a closed cell to an open cell

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does the bar mean in this context? Can you give the definitions you are working with? It would provide good context for the question.

Comment: My assumption is that it means the closure? Because the very first thing he said was : $X$ is a closed $n$-cell if $X\cong \bar{B}^n$

Comment: Just FYI, the fact that $S^{n}\setminus\{\text{one point}\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is usually proved by *stereographic projection* (in the case $n=2$ at least; I'm sure it generalizes though), which you can probably find out about online by googling. Intuitively, the point you remove from the sphere can be thought of as corresponding to a "point at infinity" for $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

Comment: "What does removing one point do so drastically..?" Removing that one point does make a huge difference, topologically.  It means the space is no longer compact.  Remember that there's no notion of distance in general topology, so just because that point is "small" doesn't mean it can't have a huge impact.

Comment: All these comments are very helpful thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing $B^n_r = \{\textbf{x}: \|\textbf{x}\| < r\}$ and so $\overline{B^n_r} = \{\textbf{x}: \|\textbf{x}\| \leq r\}$. Yes, this is a closed $n$-cell or more simply put, a closed $n$-dimension disk. However, $S^n \not \cong \overline{B^n_r}$ since the latter is a manifold with boundary. I think the notation the professor was going for, was one that Hempel uses in his 3-manifolds book i.e $\overline{B^n}(S^{n-1}) = \textbf{n}-\textrm{cell}$. Here Hempel means, if you fill in $\partial B^n = S^{n-1}$, then that gives a $\textbf{n}$-cell.

Also, if you take $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ then you can use stereographic projection to get a homeomorphism between the punctured sphere and $\mathbb{R}^n$. Again, for simplicity, you should just think of popping a hole in a sphere and expanding that puncture so that the result flatens to a plane. This is of course the visual, displaying $S^2 \setminus \{p\} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I very well may be misinterpreting the question, but I believe if you "pierce" $S^n$ at any point and flatten it into an $n$-dimensional object, it becomes $B^n$. You can visualize this using $S^2$ and $B^2$.